# Azure: What exactly does "limit" mean?

Tags: azure

I already asked my question [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/) in the comments, but I didn't received an answer - maybe because this blog is old & not many read it.
We have a Visual Studio Premium with MSDN - subscription.
Can someone answer?

Edit:
The actual question:
Is limit = fixed billing? I have a limit of 350 cores: Is there a difference in billing if I use 1 core or 350 cores?
Question 2: Why is in the limit overview no WebApp or SQL DB limit? Can I create unlimited amount of it? But then I have to pay for each one I create?

Comment: You should actually edit your question and include the comment you have put on the blog post in your question itself.

Comment: Gaurav Mantri: Thank you for this hint. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is limit = fixed billing?

No, limit is not equal to fixed billing. Billing is based on the consumption while the limit defines the quota.

To take your example, you have a limit of 350 cores. What that means is that you can consume up to 350 cores in your subscription. You will be billed for the number of cores you consume (e.g. if you consume 10 cores, you will be billed for 10 cores only).

When it comes to limits, there are [`soft limits and there are hard limits`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/). Soft limits are the default limits on your subscription when you sign up for an Azure Subscription. You can get the soft limits increased by contacting support. Hard limits are the limits in your Azure Subscription that you can't exceed. For example, currently there's a hard limit of 100 storage accounts per subscription. You can't go beyond those 100 storage accounts. If you need more storage accounts, then you would have to purchase a new subscription.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening! I'd love to have an info-text when creating a new VM (or whatever) which says: "Creating this ressource will cost you XX €/month" - but that's sth. for the support.

Comment: Have you seen the pricing calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?

Comment: Yes I know that, but it would be more transparent / user-friendly if MS informs you immediatly about the costs when you create sth.

Comment: I just tried creating a VM in Preview Portal and it does show me the pricing. http://i.stack.imgur.com/lKQng.png

Comment: I don't get this information: [http://i.imgur.com/fp8fq6f.png](http://i.imgur.com/fp8fq6f.png)

Comment: It was a screenshot of the preview portal (https://portal.azure.com) where you can see the pricing information when you are creating a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90975/discussion-between-munchkin-and-gaurav-mantri).